# django-cms not routing properly to static url?

Tags: django-cms

I'm still relatively new to Django and have just started poking around at Django-CMS, however, I can't get past the basic introduction from the [official docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/tutorial.html).

My problem may be related to sekizai, but it feels like it's a basic url issue in urls.py.

Basically, I have followed the tutorial almost exactly. The only difference is that I have my cms app under blog/, full path ~/workspace/djangocms/blog/. I have set the `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` properly under settings.py and the same goes with my `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`.

I bring up the media path and directory because if I set my base template to link to css at `{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/somecss.min.css` it works fine. However, doing the same with STATIC_URL: `{{ STATIC_URL }}css/somecss.min.css` doesn't work and produces 404s.

Also, from what I can tell, the default /static/ routes seem to work fine for other directories. The code produced by `{% cms_toolbar %}` generates fine and css from places like /static/cms/css/plugins/cms.toolbar.css are being served properly.

**Contents of urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *                                         
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'',
        include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got my answer from #django on freenode. Answering it myself here in case anyone needs it:

Mainly for django-cms, STATIC_ROOT is mainly used for assets from django-cms itself during production. If django is being run using the `python manage.py runserver` method, STATIC_ROOT  is irrelevant.

[From the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/): Use `collectstatic` to collect all the static assets used (which for django-cms will probably be under a directory like /usr/local/lib/python##/dist-packages). This shows which files STATIC_ROOT will use during production.

If you want to serve other directories with STATIC_URL, you will have to add them to the `STATICFILES_DIRS` section of `settings.py`. (Make sure to read the comments -- use the absolute paths and not relative paths). This is actually relatively obvious when making a pure Django app, however, because I wanted to strictly follow the Django-cms tutorial this was not as obvious as it should've been.

Answer (score 8):

I went round and round with this problem after following the same tutorial.

My site would load the standard welcome page and I could create CMS pages. However, when I tried to load static files in my templates I kept getting 404 errors.

The answer given by the OP helped me a lot.

Just to be clear, this worked for me:

1. Rename the static directory in the project to something like local_static
2. Add the following to settings.py

`PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "local_static/"), 
)`

This worked for me.  I can now stop pulling my hair out

Answer (score 1):

The solution is so simple I missed it too.

from settings.py;

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysitename', 'static'),
)
```

If you look inside 'mysitename' there is another folder named 'static'. If you place your files there, everything will work as you may expect it to. The 'static' folder in the same level as manage.py is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990189/2449250), but I was encountering the same issues. While I was able to serve static files for everything else, for some reason my django-cms files kept returning a 404. I checked settings.py and permissions but I did not have much luck.

On Ubuntu 14.04 running Nginx and Gunicion I as able to solve the problem by editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django
```

And I added the following code block

```
location /static/cms {
    alias /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/static/cms/;
}
```

Then I restarted Nginx and Gunicorn

```
sudo service nginx restart && sudo service gunicorn restart
```

and I was able to see all the missing static files