# django cms doesn't see static folder

Tags: django-cms

I'm very new to Django....and after hours of fighting I manage to install django cms in a virtual env. Creating some template and adding some page to my cms.
Now I 'm trying to add some css....and I have create a static folder with inside css folder and my style.css. But it seems my cms doesnt see the static folder and I have a 404 error if I try to go :8000/static/css/style.css
In my setting.py I have this

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

not sure what s wrong pls help

Answer (score 4):

You should enable URL mapping for static resource by adding the following two lines into urls.py:

```
# redirects to static media files (css, javascript, images, etc.)
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'static/'}),
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**
Check whether your project directory can be accessed by other user. `chmod -R 755` might be helpful.

---

**UPDATE 2:**
Make sure following lines are in settings.py

```
# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

---

**UPDATE 3:**
I checked the `settings.py` of my project, which is named **webui**:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'webui/static',
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: I'm following this tutorial http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/tutorial.html and it suggests relative path for the static folder. I have a urls.py file as well same content as the tutorial one.

Comment: I have tried insert those two lines..still no luck...same 404 error for static/css/style.css

Comment: yep those are in STATICFILES_FINDERS - still no luck

Comment: Make sure the URL rule for the static files is BEFORE the cms url rule.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot.

Comment: @DanielTate Yes. To figure out how django maps its path is a bit confusing. Deploy it into production will be much more confused.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to integrate django-cms into an existing Digital Ocean Django install and I was encountering the same issues. While I was able to serve static files for everything else, for some reason my django-cms files kept returning a 404. I checked settings.py and permissions but I did not have much luck.

On Ubuntu 14.04 running Nginx and Gunicion

I edited

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django
```

And I added the following code block

```
location /static/cms {
    alias /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/static/cms/;
}
```

Then I restarted Nginx and Gunicorn

```
sudo service nginx restart && sudo service gunicorn restart
```

and I was able to see all the missing static files

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
What helped me finally was to move the static files into a folder "static" of a custom app.